# Log of mounted/unmounted devices in Unix

Tags: unix, mount

Apologies in advance for the basic question.

**I need to identify the log of mounted/unmounted devices in Unix (including the timestamps when these actions where performed).**

I noticed that using the mount command is not very helpful for this purpose, since there is no indication of the timestamps when the mount/unmount operations where performed. Can anyone indicate me a possible alternative?

Thank you in advance! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such log.

You can *sometimes* identify when a filesystem was mounted by observing kernel logs, because some filesystem types will reliably log something in there each time a filesystem is mounted. But then again, some filesystem types won't. As for unmounting, I don't think you will find any logs at all.

The last modified time of `/etc/mtab` (or `/etc/mnttab` on some systems) will usually give a clue about the last time any mount or mount was performed, but that's about it.